# How do i get the information of the subscribers subscribed to my public viber account?

Tags: java, viber, viber-api, viber-bot

I want user id of the subscribers. In the [documentation](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#subscribed), it only shows the callbacks like :

```
{
   "event":"conversation_started",
   "timestamp":1457764197627,
   "message_token":4912661846655238145,
   "type":"open",
   "context":"context information",
   "user":{
      "id":"01234567890A=",
      "name":"John McClane",
      "avatar":"http://avatar.example.com",
      "country":"UK",
      "language":"en",
      "api_version":1
   },
   "subscribed":false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to documentation you provided is about Webhook Events that comes when some particular user subscribed.

What you can do is to get information about your subscribers using [Get Account Info](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#get-account-info) endpoint. Its response contains `subscribers_count` and `members` (list with fields: `id`, `name`, `avatar` and `role`).

**P.S.** the only thing that you need to check is if the public account subscribers are chat bot subscribers too.